# jQuery remove appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have a form fade away then show a message "connecting your call" then after 3 seconds the "connecting your call" message fades away and after 30 seconds the form comes back. The form is hiding and coming back just find I just can't figure out how to make the dynamic appended  tag fade. Any suggestions would be great

```
$("#form").hide().delay(30000).fadeIn('slow');
$("#formarea").append("<h3>Connecting your call...</h3>").delay(3000).$('h3').fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: remove the code $('h3') and try again ?

Comment: Why not just have the h3 in the source already with it's own ID, seeing as you never remove it?

Maybe it's just me, but I'd feel a bit *off* using something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a $ selector and should be using find:

```
$("#form").hide().delay(30000).fadeIn('slow');
$("#formarea")
    .append("<h3>Connecting your call...</h3>")
    .delay(3000)
    .find('h3')
        .fadeOut('slow');
```

The problem with delaying through is that it only works on the effects queue, and the next item in the chain is not an effects function. Try this:

```
$("#form").hide().delay(30000).fadeIn('slow');
    $("#formarea")
        .append("<h3>Connecting your call...</h3>")
        .find('h3')
            .delay(3000)
                .fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: that seems to be ignoring the delay. :-/

Comment: The edit worked, I never realized that you could chain things with tabs that's super intresting and cool.

Comment: The whitespace obviously doesn't change how the code operates, it just makes it easier and cleaner to read.

Comment: oh, I feel silly now, I didn't even notice you changed the position fo `.find` and `.delay` :-S

Answer (score 1):

$("#formarea > h3").fadeOut(3000);